# Laravel Eloquent using an alias with the with() function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Good day. Is it possible to use an alias name when using the with() function in laravel? For an example:

```
$posts = Post::where(/*condition*/)->with('user as friend')->get();
```

Comment: One post can have many friend or just one?

Comment: `$post->user` and `$post->friend` are two different results. But I had already created a function that checks `if ($post->friend->id == ?)`, I was trying to avoid duplicating it with: `if ($post->user->id == ?)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you already have a relationship definition for `friend` and it's result is different from `user`?

Answer (score 10):

Short answer is no, but you can define your relationship with the alias you want to use and eager load that.

```
class Post extends Model
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function friend(){
        return $this->user()
    }
}

$posts = Post::where(/*condition*/)->with('friend')->get();
```

Comment: `$post->user` and `$post->friend` are two different results. But I had already created a function that checks `if ($post->friend->id == ?)`, I was trying to avoid duplicating it like: `if ($post->user->id == ?)`

Comment: Some one upvoted my answer, for some reason. I forgot to follow up on this. Is there any need for an update @LukhoMdingi ?

Comment: I never actually found a solution to this. I had to work around it.