# Laravel - Filter a collection

Tags: laravel

I am retrieving a bunch of records from the database to display:

```
    $students = $bursary_administrator->students()/*->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7])*/
    ->whereHas('bursaries.statuses', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7])
            ->whereYear('status_start','<=',$request->year)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request){
                $query->whereYear('status_end','>=',$request->year)
                    ->orWhereNull('status_end');
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request){
                $query->whereYear('registration_date','<=',$request->year)
                    ->orWhereNull('registration_date');
            });
    })
    ->with('bursaries','bursaries.statuses','bursaries.enrolments','bursaries.enrolments.courses')
    ->orderBy('student_name')->orderBy('student_middle_names')->orderBy('student_surname')->get();
```

Im displaying all these records in a table so need to fetch all of them.
I also however, need to get some count()'s based on this data. Now, I know I can perform individual queries for each count, but since I've already fetched all the data, I think it will be more optimised to just count the filtered data?
However, I am not winning. Both attempts listed below yield `0` as the output:

eg: using "where":

```
    $summary['students_transfer'] = $students->where('status', '7')->count();
```

or, using "filter":

```
    $summary['students_postgraduate'] = $students->filter(function ($student) {
        return $student->qualification == 'Postgraduate' || $student->qualification == 'Postgraduate in Training';
    })->count();
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) in combination with [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public function scopeTransfer($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', '7');
    }

    public function scopePostgraduate($query)
    {
        return $query->where('qualification', 'Postgraduate')
                     ->orWhere('qualification', 'Postgraduate in Training');
    }
}
```

```
class Bursary_Administrator extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function students_transfer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class)->transfer();
    }

    public function students_postgraduate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class)->postgraduate();
    }
}
```

```
$students = $bursary_administrator->students()/*->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7])*/
    ->whereHas('bursaries.statuses', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7])
            ->whereYear('status_start','<=',$request->year)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request){
                $query->whereYear('status_end','>=',$request->year)
                    ->orWhereNull('status_end');
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request){
                $query->whereYear('registration_date','<=',$request->year)
                    ->orWhereNull('registration_date');
            });
    })
    ->with('bursaries','bursaries.statuses','bursaries.enrolments','bursaries.enrolments.courses')
    ->withCount('students_transfer', 'students_postgraduate')
    ->orderBy('student_name')->orderBy('student_middle_names')->orderBy('student_surname')->get();
```

Comment: No this isnt quite what I am looking for. I am not looking to extend the model. I just want some counts off the results retrieved.

Comment: Please add this requirement to the question so that others might not have to assume like I had to.

Comment: The problem is that it seems that [you can't alias a relation without modifying the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018265/laravel-eloquent-using-an-alias-with-the-with-function) and you need to query the same relationship multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Reason it wasnt working was because I was thinking of it as a database result instead of parent/child relationship.

ie, instead of:

```
$summary['students_postgraduate'] = $students->filter(function ($student) {
    return $student->qualification == 'Postgraduate' || $student->qualification == 'Postgraduate in Training';
})->count();
```

I should of been doing:

```
$summary['students_postgraduate'] = $students->filter(function ($student) {
    return $student->bursaries[0]->qualification == 'Postgraduate' || $student->bursaries[0]->qualification == 'Postgraduate in Training';
})->count();
```